# How to know ip/host and port of Google reCAPTCHA v3? (need to whitelist them)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, wireshark

I have to run `Google reCAPTCHA v3` on CentOs which has a restrict access to the Internet.

And the network Admin only allows traffics that I specify `source, dest, port...`.

I'm trying to get those info by using Wireshark on localhost that has of course no limit to the Internet.
I've filtered out `http` traffics and there doesn't appear to be any traffic going to or coming from Google. Or maybe I'm not good at Wireshark.

The language is `java` and I've implemented `google-cloud-recaptchaenterprise-3.25.0.jar`.

I need to know the destination ip or host and port of Google reCAPTCHA v3.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify indicates a POST request to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` is used to verify.

Comment: @ceejayoz It seems on the client-side. I've installed google-cloud-sdk on the server, and it validates user's reCAPTCHA response on the server-side. And I need to know where that traffics go.

Comment: No, that's the server side call. The very first sentence says "from your application's backend" and the call requires your app's secret.

Comment: @ceejayoz I disabled the google domain by setting `127.0.0.1       www.google.com` on hosts of my test server(Win server). And it still works. It shouldn't work, I think.

Comment: @ceejayoz I refered https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment-website?hl=ko#create-assessment-Java and there's no api url specified..

Comment: Try https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com, then; https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! I tried to block 
 both `recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com`, `googleapis.com` and finally it's not working. Maybe they are what Im looking for.

Comment: @Deckard, 

If this solved your issue, can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of community.

Comment: @Srividya I've whitelist `recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com`, `accounts.google.com` and it works fine. It seems the former one is used to communicate to the google server for a assessment of each recaptcha request and the latter one is used to init and activate? the project in Google Cloud SDK. @ceejayoz thank you again and if you don't mind please post your comment as answer so I can pick it up.